# Leer una tupla y multiplicar las veces que se repite por su valor

Tags: python, tuplas

Estoy atascado en un ejercicio en el que tengo que leer una lista con tuplas y multiplicar la frecuencia que se repiten unas palabras por su valor.

Probé el codigo de un par de formas pero en todas me da un error :

```
resultado =[('enfermedad', '-0.333'), ('enfermedad', '-0.333'), ('mata', '-0.25'), ('enfermedad', '-0.333'), ('pesar', '-0.562'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('enfermedad', '-0.333'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('enfermedad', '-0.333')]

def sentimiento_negativo(resultado):
    total =[]
    for x in zip(*resultado):
        cod = x[0][0]
        suma = sum(valor[1] for valor in x)
        total.append((cod, suma))
        print(total)
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el error que te da? Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Además puedes leer [mre]. Haz clic en [edit] y agrega lo que haga falta. Para insertar código con formato inicia una linea con tres bacticks, por ejemplo: `\`\`\`python`, luego escribe el código a partir de la siguiente linea, bien indentado y finaliza con una linea con tres backticks nuevamente:  `\`\`\``. Como ves, la primera linea tiene el nombre del lenguaje, ayudará al formato de color. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Una herramienta de depuración muy importante es el `print()`. Este te permite ir dejando registro del contenido de las variables. Por ejemplo:

```
for x in zip(*resultado):
    print(x)
```

nos mostraras con que estas trabajando dentro del ciclo:

```
('enfermedad', 'enfermedad', 'mata', 'enfermedad', 'pesar', 'vacuna', 'vacuna', 'vacuna', 'vacuna', 'enfermedad', 'vacuna', 'enfermedad')
('-0.333', '-0.333', '-0.25', '-0.333', '-0.562', '-0.25', '-0.25', '-0.25', '-0.25', '-0.333', '-0.25', '-0.333')
```

Entonces tu iteración hace dos pasadas. En la primera `x` vale

```
('enfermedad', 'enfermedad', 'mata', 'enfermedad', 'pesar', 'vacuna', 'vacuna', 'vacuna', 'vacuna', 'enfermedad', 'vacuna', 'enfermedad')
```

y en la segunda `x` vale

```
('-0.333', '-0.333', '-0.25', '-0.333', '-0.562', '-0.25', '-0.25', '-0.25', '-0.25', '-0.333', '-0.25', '-0.333')
```

No creo que eso fuera lo que tenías en mente.

#### Solución Pythonica

```
def sentimiento_negativo(resultado):
    total = {}
    for enfermedad, valor in resultado:
        total[enfermedad] = total.get(enfermedad, 0) + float(valor)
    return total
```

Aqui tenemos un `for` con desempaquetado. El `for` va entrega una tupla que separo de inmediato en sus componente `enfermedad` y `valor`. No hay necesidad de usar índices.

De los dos valores extraidos solo nos interesa `valor`, que viene como cadena y convertimos con `float()`.

Los totales por enfermedad los llevamos en el diccionario `total`. En cada ciclo sumamos `valor` a lo acumulado por `total[enfermedad]`. Para recuperar el valor acumulado previamente, usamos

```
total.get(enfermedad, 0)
```

que devuelve el acumulado (si lo hay) o cero, si la enfermedad no está registrada.

#### Demo

```
resultado =[('enfermedad', '-0.333'), ('enfermedad', '-0.333'), ('mata', '-0.25'), ('enfermedad', '-0.333'), ('pesar', '-0.562'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('enfermedad', '-0.333'), ('vacuna', '-0.25'), ('enfermedad', '-0.333')]

def sentimiento_negativo(resultado):
    total = {}
    for enfermedad, valor in resultado:
        total[enfermedad] = total.get(enfermedad, 0) + float(valor)
    return total

for enfermedad, total in sentimiento_negativo(resultado).items():
    print(enfermedad, total)
```

produce:

```
enfermedad -1.665
mata -0.25
pesar -0.562
vacuna -1.25

Process finished with exit code 0
```